# Bash/R searching columns in a huge table

Tags: r, bash, search

I have a huge table I want to extract information from. Firstly, I want to extract a certain line based on a pattern -> I've done that successfully with grep. However this line has loads of columns and I'm interested only in a couple of them that have a certain pattern in them (partial match - beginning of the string). Is it possible to extract only the columns and the number of the column (the nth column) for some partial matches? Hope I was clear enough.

Languages: Preferably in bash but I can also work in R, alternatively I'm open to suggestions if you think another language can be more helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at awk, it's a bit rough to get started with, but it sounds like it would solve your needs. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html

Comment: Or search this site for `awk` posts/tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk is perfect for stuff like this. To help you write a script I think we need more details. But I'm guessing you'll want to use the print feature of `awk`. To print out the nth column of a file "your_file" do:

```
awk '{print $n}' your_file
```

In solving your problem you may also want to loop over all N columns which you can do via:

```
for i in {1..N} ;
do
    awk -v col=${i} '{print $col}' your_file ;
done
```